# Cannot open session when using su

Tags: kubernetes

I'm attempting to launch a container that launches its process by running several commands as another user. The commands are executed using `su`. I first thought this was a problem in the storage backend, as the container was built on devicemapper but run on aufs, but the container starts correctly when I use docker run. I also thought that this was an issue with the container being privileged, but I've already taken the steps necessary to run privileged containers on my cluster, as well as added the `privileged: true` flag to my ReplicationController definition. Any help is appreciated.

Kube v1

Docker 1.7.0

Mesos 0.23.0

Edit: So after some troubleshooting, it appears that my issue is that Kubernetes is not setting the container to privileged correctly. Even though I have *--allow-privileged=true* set for my apiserver, and the below snippet from my ReplicationController:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: oracledb
      image: bradams/devops:oracle-test
      privileged: true
```

Not sure what else I should be doing here.

Comment: Some things to try which could help answer your question:  Does the container run as expected if started directly using docker on one of your nodes?  What if you start a Pod interactively with this command: kubectl run -i --tty <imagename> -- sh ; then are you able to type in su commands and have them work?

Comment: To the first point, I've tried that and yes it works as expected. To the second point, I'll give that a shot and report back.

Comment: So the second option doesn't work. Looking around, I thought it may have been a file limit issue, but changing that had no effect. I think perhaps Kubernetes isn't correctly setting the container as privileged. I can't think of any other answer at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

`spec:
  containers:
    - name: oracledb
      image: bradams/devops:oracle-test
      securityContext:
        privileged: true`

You are missing nesting under `securityContext:`.  This changed between v1beta3 and v1, and is documented here: http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/api.html#v1-conversion-tips-from-v1beta3

If you try creating your pod using `kubectl create --validate=true ...` then I think this problem would be caught, with an error message.

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually just discovered I was running the wrong version of the binaries, so after updating and figuring out the syntax, I was able to move past this. The problem now, is that even though my apiserver should allow for privileged containers, when Mesos schedules the task and kubelet is launched on the node, it refuses to start with  _--allow-privileged=true_. I can see in my Mesos slave log that it starts with the flag false.